# Filter specific value from Tshark JSON output

Tags: json, duplicates, key, jq, tshark

I would like to extract the "tls.handshake.certificate_raw" values, but without success so far. The big JSON is killing me.

Here's my JSON file: [Download](https://gofile.io/?c=1dCkxL)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  The question should be written so as not to require downloading a file (especially one that is not transparent): a description plus SMALL representative snippet and the expected output would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSON has objects with duplicate keys, an approach that does not use jq's normal object semantics is warranted.

jq's streaming parser (invoked with the --stream option) allows one to handle objects with duplicate keys:

```
jq --stream -c '(.[0]|index("tls.handshake.certificate_raw")) as $ix
                | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix+1:]' Tshark.json |
    jq -nc 'fromstream(inputs)'
```

This produces 503 entities, the first of which is:

```
["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",109,2275,0,30]
```

#### Explanation

The first invocation of jq uses jq's streaming parser to extract the [path, atomicValue] pairs of interest. The second invocation reconstructs the relevant entities.

### Resources

Here are the main stats from a run using `/usr/bin/time -lp` on a Mac Mini:

```
real         5.35
user         5.31
sys          0.05
  13279232  maximum resident set size
```

Comment: - that's an improvement! but there's more entries (503 in total). if you run it with `jtc -mmrw'<tls.handshake.certificate_raw>l:<>f><i:' Tshark.json` - you'll see all 503 entries, and the one you shown is actually a second entry.

Comment: @Dmitry - Revised answer produces 503 entries as you said.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitry - I'm not sure what was wrong with the previous approach :-(

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that if a JSON object in the file has a specific key more than once, then only the last one is relevant. If this assumption is not valid, then one option would be to use jq's streaming parser.

The following shows that a simple application of jq to retrieve the named key requires about 26MB RAM. Is that a problem in this day and age?

```
/usr/bin/time -lp jq '.. | objects | .["tls.handshake.certificate_raw"] // empty'  Tshark.json
```

#### Output:

```
[
  "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",
  1778,
  1127,
  0,
  30
]
real         1.42
user         1.34
sys          0.03
  26693632  maximum resident set size
```

Comment: hi @peak, this is by far not the first object from the source json. The source json has duplicate labels in objects, which require respective processing (there are 503 labels `"tls.handshake.certificate_raw"` in total, in this json).

Comment: @dmitry - Sorry, I missed the bit about duplicate keys!

Answer (score 0):

My final command:

```
jq --stream -c '(.[0]|index("tls.handshake.certificate_raw")) as $ix
            | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix+1:]' Tshark.json |
jq -r -nc 'fromstream(inputs)[0]' | sort -u > Certificates.txt
```

I grab only the first value from the array and remove the double quotes. After a sort uniq I write the SSL certificates line by line into a file.

Thanks a lot for your great assistance!

Comment: given a big bulk of investigation and steering jq solution was done using `jtc`, I think i'm entitled to show also a jtc based solution: `jtc -mmjw'<tls.handshake.certificate_raw>l:<>f><i:<>F1[0]' / -jw'><g:' / -qqw'><q:' Tshark.json >Certificates.txt`